# Why is my code being ran backwards? Or so it seems?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have an `IBAction` that when called, registers a user information with Parse.com... I have only implemented the email and username methods, since i need to make sure that prior to submission to the server i added a counter `int`, if the `counter == 2` it will execute the registration... well to my surprise, when I run the code, it gets ran backwards, so my conditional statement at the bottom is not even reviewed, why is this the case?

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)signMeUpButton:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    counter = 0;



    user = [PFUser user];

    NSString *emailFromTextField = self.emailTF.text;

    if ([self isValidEmailAddress:emailFromTextField]) {


    [self emailHasBeenTaken:emailFromTextField completion:^(BOOL emailIsTaken, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // TODO: handle any errors here
            return;
        }

        if (!emailIsTaken) {
            emailString = emailFromTextField;
            user.email = emailString;
            counter++;
            NSLog(@"The email is %@ the counter is %i", emailString, counter);

        }
        else {
            [self duplicateEmail];
        }
    }];


    }

    NSString *usernameFromTextField = self.usernameTF.text;
    if (usernameFromTextField.length >= 1) {
        [self usernameHasBeenTaken:usernameFromTextField completion:^(BOOL usernameIsTaken, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                return;
            }

            if (!usernameIsTaken) {
                usernameString = usernameFromTextField;
                user.username = usernameString;
                counter++;
                NSLog(@"The username is %@ and the counter is %i", usernameString, counter);
            }
            else {
                //
            }
        }];
    }

    if (counter == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Its working");
    }
}
```

And this is what I get on my console when i run it, as you can see the `usernameHasBeenTaken` is being called FIRST, even though I have it written second... why is that?

```
2014-07-17 23:18:12.169 app[28210:60b] in the usernameHasBeenTaken. USERNAME IS NOT EXISTENT
2014-07-17 23:18:12.170 app[28210:60b] The username is sample and the counter is 1
2014-07-17 23:18:15.328 app[28210:60b] in the emailHasBeenTaken, EMAIL IS NOT EXISTENT
2014-07-17 23:18:15.328 app[28210:60b] The email is sample@email.com the counter is 2
```

These are my 2 methods: `usernameHasBeenTaken` and `emailHasBeenTaken`

```
- (void)emailHasBeenTaken:(NSString *)email completion:(void(^)(BOOL emailIsTaken, NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    void (^completionCopy)(BOOL, NSError *) = [completionBlock copy];

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:email];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"in the emailHasbeenTaken ERROR HAS OCCURRED");
            if (completionCopy) {
                completionCopy(NO, error);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (objects.count > 0) {
            NSLog(@"in the emailHasbeenTaken EMAIL IS DUPLICATE");
            if (completionCopy) {
                completionCopy(YES, nil);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"in the emailHasBeenTaken, EMAIL IS NOT EXISTENT");
            if (completionCopy) {
                completionCopy(NO, nil);
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (void) usernameHasBeenTaken:(NSString *)username completion:(void(^)(BOOL usernameIsTaken, NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    void (^completionCopy)(BOOL, NSError *) = [completionBlock copy];
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:username];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"in the usernameHasBeenTaken ERROR HAS OCCURED");
            if (completionCopy) {
                completionCopy(NO, error);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (objects.count > 0) {
            NSLog(@"in the usernameHasBeenTaken USERNAME IS DUPLICATE");
            if (completionCopy) {
                completionCopy(NO, nil);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"in the usernameHasBeenTaken. USERNAME IS NOT EXISTENT");
            if (completionCopy) {
                completionCopy(NO, nil);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Your `emailHasBeenTaken` and `usernameHasBeenTaken` methods are using a completion block, which implies that they are running asynchronously - if you added these methods to the question it would help - therefor there is no guarantee on the order of completion.

Comment: @Paulw11 I will add them now, is there any way to ensure that they do in fact are executed in an explicit order?

Comment: @iBull yes run your code synchronously

Comment: @meda can you please explain how I can do that?

Comment: I would suggest that you look at creating a Parse Cloud Code function to validate your email and username in a single call and return a status that indicates OK, duplicate email or duplicate username.  You can then validate both fields in a single call and in the completion block simply call your method to create your user

Comment: i will absolutely look into that @Paulw11 thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of a completion block indicates that you are running them asynchronously. If that is the case then your password condition gets hit immediately after you invoke `emailHasBeenTaken:completion:`

If you must run async, which you should if you are hitting a web service, you need to nest your calls in the completion blocks.

#### Edit

It appears that this is the case. The Parse API runs async, to avoid locking the UI thread. You will need to nest your callbacks like I show below.

```
- (IBAction)signMeUpButton:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    counter = 0;



    user = [PFUser user];

    NSString *emailFromTextField = self.emailTF.text;

    if ([self isValidEmailAddress:emailFromTextField]) {


    [self emailHasBeenTaken:emailFromTextField completion:^(BOOL emailIsTaken, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // TODO: handle any errors here
            return;
        }

        if (!emailIsTaken) {
            emailString = emailFromTextField;
            user.email = emailString;
            counter++;
            NSLog(@"The email is %@ the counter is %i", emailString, counter);

            NSString *usernameFromTextField = self.usernameTF.text;
            if (usernameFromTextField.length >= 1) {
                [self usernameHasBeenTaken:usernameFromTextField completion:^(BOOL usernameIsTaken, NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        return;
                    }

                if (!usernameIsTaken) {
                    usernameString = usernameFromTextField;
                    user.username = usernameString;
                    counter++;
                    NSLog(@"The username is %@ and the counter is %i", usernameString, counter);
            }
            else {
                //
            }

            if (counter == 2) {
                NSLog(@"Its working");
            }
        }];
    }
        }
        else {
            [self duplicateEmail];
        }
    }];


    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your code, but my conditional at the end `if (counter == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Its working");
    }` is not being called. Any idea why?

Comment: My mistake, I missed that. That should be moved in to the end of your second block.

Comment: Got it, I get confused when there is nested statements like this. If you dont mind, what do you think of the comment that @Paulw11 made about doing it all from a single call? How difficult can this be to accomplish? I am somewhat new to obj-c and definitely inexperienced when it comes to objective-c blocks

Comment: I believe he is [referring to this documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-signup/iOS), that shows you can attempt to sign the user up and check the error in one shot. The error will let the user know if the email already exists or if the username was already taken. They do it one one call. Next, in the completion handler, you just have to check the error message for failed username/email, without needing to blocks.

Comment: I've spent 2 days working on this and it just clicked! Thanks @Johnathon & Paulw11 wish there was more like you guys around this site that understood we are not all experts :)